Why is Canvas text thicker than SVG text with the same font size and font family?
I noticed that if I draw the text with the same font size and font family, the text on canvas is thicker than the text on SVG. Does anyone know what causes this and if it can be fixed? Is it possible to make text on Canvas the same as SVG or vice versa?
image


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      canvas,
      svg,
      text,
      tspan {
        text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      }
      canvas,
      svg {
        border: 1px solid gainsboro;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2 style="color: #000">SVG</h2>
    <h2 id="devicePixelRatio"></h2>
    <svg height="200" width="200">
      <text id="text" x="5" y="30" font-size="25px" fill="#c7862c">
        I love SVG!
      </text>
    </svg>
    <canvas id="canvas" height="200" width="200"> </canvas>
  </body>

  <script>
    const size = 200;
    const scale = window.devicePixelRatio;
    const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
    const scaleEl = document.querySelector('#devicePixelRatio');
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    const textEl = document.querySelector('#text');
    const styles = getComputedStyle(textEl);
    canvas.style.width = `${size}px`;
    canvas.style.height = `${size}px`;
    canvas.width = Math.floor(size * scale);
    canvas.height = Math.floor(size * scale);

    ctx.save();
    ctx.scale(scale, scale);
    ctx.fillStyle = '#c7862c';
    ctx.font = `${styles.fontWeight} ${styles.fontSize} ${styles.fontFamily}`;
    ctx.textRendering = 'geometricPrecision';
    ctx.fillText('I love SVG!', 5, 30);
    ctx.restore();
    scaleEl.innerHTML += 'devicePixelRatio: ' + scale;
  </script>
</html>



Expected behavior: Text on Canvas the same as SVG or vice versa

Because you're on a high-res monitor. If your monitor's dPR is say 2, 4 pixels will be used to generate a single px (CSS unit). The svg is rendered along the page layout and thus the engine can scale it before it makes a bitmap of it. The canvas on the other end is already a bitmap, so when it gets scaled the engine uses a interpolation method that will make it "blurry". You can circumvent that by scaling the canvas yourself, using its width and height attributes to match your monitor's dPR, and CSS to shrink it back to the expected layout size.

Ps: there are many duplicates but I'm AFK for the moment and can't easily search for them...

I think i'm not on high-res monitor.  My browser( chrome version 129.0.6668.90 (Official Build) (64-bit)) has devicePixelRatio is 1

Ah, I missed you posted a screenshot earlier. So yes, even on 1x monitors you'll have that kind of difference (which is a lot less noticeable than what we have on high-res monitors btw) This is because the SVG can use a better aliasing method for the text than it does for canvas. If you zoom a lot on your screenshot you can see that the SVG text has redish pixels on the side. That's sub-pixel rendering. This indeed renders better on LCD monitors, but for it to work, the engine has to know the background color of the text. 1/2

2/2 Since a canvas can be transparent and is converted to bitmap before it's even in the page, the engine can't use this technique and has to resort on alpha-smoothing instead. There used to be a trick in Firefox when you knew the background would be opaque, through getContext({ alpha: false }), but I'm not sure it still stands and I don't have a system that does use subpixel rendering at hand anymore.

Note that I just closed as a duplicate of an old Q/A, but you probably don't want to use the method there because most of your users won't experience that issue anymore. You may want to instead use the CSS scaling and even force it to a minimum of scale x2 as this might get better results on some x1 systems too.
